# How to access file located in called workflow from caller workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

What is the best way of accessing the `main.py` from called-workflow? Should I really checkout the called-workflow repository in caller-workflow like below?

**caller-workflow**

```
name: Jellyfish DORA

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  checkout:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11
        with:
          repository: <organization>/repository
          path: main.py --> ??
  deploy:
    uses: <organization>/<repository>/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@main
    with:
       ....
```

Here is the folder structure of called-workflow's repository.

```
.
├── CODEOWNERS
├── main.py
├── .github
    ├── workflows
       ├── deploy.yml
```

**called-workflow**

```
name: "Deploy"

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      repository-name:
        required: true
        type: string
        .....

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11 # v4
    
          - name: setup python
            uses: actions/setup-python@0a5c61591373683505ea898e09a3ea4f39ef2b9c # v5
            with:
              python-version: "3.10"
    
          - name: install python packages
            run: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install requests
          - name: execute py script
            env:
              REPO_NAME: ${{ inputs.repository-name }}
              ...
            run: python main.py
```

Comment: The reusable workflow runs in the context of the calling repository, so it's not aware of anything else existing in the same repository as it is defined.

Comment: Yes, but what is the best way of achieving this then?

Comment: You could package some of your steps into a separate action, where you do have access to files relative to where the action is defined.